# Difference between apart and separate

Tags: word-difference

What is the difference between apart and separate?

From the dictonary I think that both are the opposite of together.

Answer (score 4):

They are very close in meaning. I think the difference is that if you describe things as *apart*, there is an implication that they should be, or used to be, or might be, together. Describing them as *separate* does not have this implication; in fact it may have (weakly) the opposite implication that they do not belong together.

Comment: That might explain why you can *pull the edges apart*, but you wouldn't be likely to *pull them separate*. But I'm not sure it explains @Chad's *The two trees are far apart*  (where I can't really see any semantic or syntactic reason why ***separate*** doesn't work; it seems to be more a matter of "established idiomatic preference").

Comment: I think "far apart" is a different meaning of apart - where a physical distance is specified.

Comment: But you would say _pull to separate the edges_

Answer (score 2):

Both words can be used in a variety of contexts, so it's hard to concisely express when one word is more fitting than the other. Here are some differences that come to my mind:

- I would use **apart** to describe two people in a close relationship who did not live near each other: *My brother and I were apart for two years*.
- I would use **separate** to describe when two people don't share the same living quarters: *My brother and I had separate bedrooms*.
- I would use **apart** when emphasizing distance between two things: *Our bedrooms were far apart, but our sisters had bedrooms that were close together*.
- I would use **separate** when talking about something that is related to, yet different from, something else: *I paid $40 for these teacups and saucers, but the teapot came separate.*

However, there are times when the two words could be used pretty much interchangeably: *The hermit lived separate/apart from everyone else*.

In addition, *separate* is more readily converted to a noun (*separation*), and an adverb (*separately*). *Separate* can also be used as a verb (although it changes pronunciation): *Separate the dark clothes from the whites before you start the wash*.

Comment: I'd say _separate_ has shades of quality and _apart_ of distance. also, _apart_ is also readily converted to a verb _my brother and I parted_, _our bedrooms were parted by several metres but our sisters' rooms were not parted at all_ etc.

Answer (score 1):

Separate can mean "different":

> Those are two separate questions.

You could not substitute the word "apart" in the sentence above.

> The two trees are far apart.

This says that there is a large distance between the trees. It would not make sense to say "far separate" here (though you could say that the trees are "widely separated").

Comment: It may be a "bad" usage but I definitely hear that kind if thing colloquially.